# How do I combine the top n rows with a summary function the remaining rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I wonder if there is an easy way to do the following, perhaps using dplyr:

The data in R built-in dataset "women" is:

```
    height  weight
1   58  115
2   59  117
3   60  120
4   61  123
5   62  126
6   63  129
7   64  132
8   65  135
9   66  139
10  67  142
11  68  146
12  69  150
13  70  154
14  71  159
15  72  164
```

I need a function that would give me, for instance, the first 5 rows combined with the average of the remaining rows, like this:

```
    height  weight
1   58  115
2   59  117
3   60  120
4   61  123
5   62  126
6   67.5    145   # average of the remaining 10 rows
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Just for clarity, the mean of `women$height[6:16]` is `67.5`. Are you wanting some rounding?

Comment: @IanCampbell sorry, I used Excel to calculate and forgot do disable the automatic rounding

Comment: @BroVic I actually haven't tried anything yet, it's all very new to me, I'm still learning

Comment: Dont be afraid to try and fail before asking questions. You'll learn quicker that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a grouping variable based on row number and then do the `mean` across

```
library(dplyr)
women %>%
   group_by(group =  case_when(row_number() <=5 ~ row_number())) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ round(mean(.)))) %>%
   select(-group)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  height weight
#*  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     58    115
#2     59    117
#3     60    120
#4     61    123
#5     62    126
#6     68    145
```

---

Or with `bind_rows`

```
women %>% 
    slice(seq_len(5)) %>% 
    bind_rows(women %>% 
                 slice(-(1:5)) %>% 
                 summarise(across(everything(), mean)))
```

---

Or another option is `base R`

```
rbind(women[1:5,], round(colMeans(women[-(1:5),])))
```

Comment: Thank you, I liked your last option very much, it's simple and effective!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`:

```
women %>%
  group_by(group = c(1:5,rep(6,n()-5))) %>%
  summarize_all(mean)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  group height weight
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1   58      115
2     2   59      117
3     3   60      120
4     4   61      123
5     5   62      126
6     6   67.5    145
```